# Wire up different events and different selectors to same function

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

Let's say I have some code like this:

```
$('#mywrapper')
    .on('click', 'button', myFunction)
    .on('change', 'input', myFunction)
;
```

Is there a more efficient way to wire both event and selectors up to the same function?

Comment: Damn... how much shorter can your code get?

Comment: seems pretty efficient already

Comment: the reasoning for this is that I would like these two events to always be linked together, as they essentially indicate the same action.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not really actually.  The only real variation here is that you can pass an object to .on() that will define all your events in one go:

```
$("div.test").on({
  click: myFunc,
  mouseenter: myFunc
});
```

Comment: this only wires up one selector to a series of events. i was hoping for multiple selectors and multiple events to one callback

Comment: Theoretically, you can move multiple events and multiple selectors in one bind: `$('#something').on('click change', 'button, input', myFunc)`. The problem here is that now you've bound events to elements  where it may not make sense and cause weird functionality. Like the "click" event bound to the input field e.g..

Comment: right. which is why i'm asking this question in the first place :) i can accept that there's no better way, i was just wondering if there was.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a 'plain object' to pass both at once:

```
$('#mywrapper').on({
    click: myFunc,
    mouseenter: myFunc
});
```

[jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (example towards the bottom)

Comment: as i pointed out to @joeltine, this wires up one selector to multiple events, but not multiple selectors and multiple events to one callback